# Display data in family tree view with where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]

I want to display data in family tree. I can easily get using below query. i faced problem in where condition on city. If i search city is *paris*  then it will display only those data which are belong to *paris* but i want to display those data which have family head belong to *paris*. (if family head belong to *paris* then display all child of family head. No need for child to be from Paris). -1 is root level head

```
; WITH CTE 
AS ( 
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.ContactId) as MCID , 1 as CID 
    ,c.contactId
    FROM ContactDetail c where c.FamilyHeadId = -1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cte.MCID as MCID ,
    CONVERT(INT,(
                    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CTE.CID) + 
                    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.ContactId))
                )
            ) AS CID

    ,p.contactId
    FROM ContactDetail p INNER JOIN cte ON p.FamilyHeadId = CTE.ContactId

)

select * from CTE 
inner join ContactDetail b on cte.contactid = b.contactid 
order by mcid,CID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the filter on "Paris" into the CTE's initial anchor query (i.e. the search for family head will also be constrained by the city). This predicate must not however be repeated on the recursive query after the `UNION` in the CTE (since there is no requirement to constrain children). I've assumed a column `CityName` on `ContactDetail` but presumably your actual model has a normalized relationship to a City table or such:

```
; WITH CTE 
 AS ( 
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.ContactId) as MCID, 1 as CID, c.contactId
    FROM ContactDetail c 
    WHERE c.FamilyHeadId = -1 AND c.City = 'Paris'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT cte.MCID as MCID,
        CONVERT(INT, (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CTE.CID) + 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.ContactId)))) AS CID
        ,p.contactId
    FROM ContactDetail p 
        INNER JOIN cte ON p.FamilyHeadId = CTE.ContactId

)
SELECT * FROM CTE 
INNER JOIN ContactDetail b on cte.contactid = b.contactid 
order by mcid, CID;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ce9d0/1)

Note that you can also avoid the final join in the outer query back to the same table by emitting all the required fields from the 2 CTE queries as per this [updated SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ce9d0/2)

Comment: I have only one table. please write your query in detail.

Comment: I've expanded the full query and added a [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ce9d0/1). All ContactId's ultimately have FamilyHeadId 1 as an ancestor (who is the only FamHead in Paris), with the exception of 6,7 and 14. As an aside, you might look at [Hierarchical Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as an alternate solution.

Comment: Thanx sir your query is working fine for when root level(-1) head is from paris. but how it can be possible to display when main family head is not from paris but sub head is from paris then it should be display in data from sub head to end child

Comment: I remove familyHeadId=-1 condition and i got repeated data. it should be distinct.

Comment: Thats a very different (and more difficult problem). It will likely require two passes through the data. Do you mean "If ANY of the family hierarchy live in Paris, then the query should return the ENTIRE Family Tree. I would suggest asking a new question, and explaining clearly what your output expectations are.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right. sure I will write another question.

Answer (score 0):

actually variable table could be more better than cursor so I utilize that plz check this query It should help you out.

```
declare  @allheadCount int, @allheadCounttree int , @contactId int 
declare  @city varchar(50), @name varchar(50)

set @allheadCounttree =0

DECLARE @familyTree TABLE
(
familyId int IDENTITY(1,1),
contactId int ,
familyHeadId int,
Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
city varchar(50) NOT NULL,
headcity varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

select @allheadCount = count(contactid) from contactdetail where familyheadid = -1

WHILE @allheadCount <> @allheadCounttree 
BEGIN

    select top 1 @contactid = contactId, @name=name, @city=city from contactdetail where familyheadid = -1 and contactid not in (select distinct contactid from @familytree )

    insert into @familyTree (contactid,familyheadid,name,city,headcity) Values (@contactId,-1,@name,@city,@city) 

    insert into @familyTree (contactid,familyheadid,name,city,headcity) 
    select contactid,@contactId,name,city,@city from contactdetail where familyheadid = @contactid

    select @allheadCounttree  = count(contactid) from @familyTree where familyheadid = -1

END

select  * from @familyTree where city = lower('Paris') or headcity = lower('paris') order by familyid
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    select * from contactdetail where city = lower('paris')
    union
    select contactId, FamilyHeadId, Name, City from contactdetail cross apply (
        select contactid as pcontactid, city as pcity from contactdetail where familyheadid = -1 
    ) parentdata
        where pcity =  lower('paris') and pcontactid = familyheadid
```

Comment: Result is not display in family tree view

Comment: plz use mine query @sql end and see the results first on sql end

Comment: I think you want the separation of parents along with their child as well. Am I right?

Comment: display result in root to leaf order

Comment: @VishalPatel ve you checked mine soln.

Comment: as mine query is now making all tree structure for parent and individual plz check this and let me know if it still not as you want